# Clickable Container with inner links

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, containers

My apologies if this already exists but I was unable to find anything like it. My stupid question is:

I have a clickable container with links inside that looks kinda like:

```
<div onclick="someFunction()">
    <...>
    <...>
    <button onclick="otherFunction()">
</div>
```

I want to be able to click anywhere in the container and open up something but I also want to be able to have the button inside work. My appreciation for all assistance in advance and apologies for the dumb question.

Comment: So you wanted to say whenever you click anywhere in the container a div appear with a button in it ?

Answer (score 1):

It will work like ur thinking, when u click on button, click will fire on both on ur button as well as on div check codepen

event.stopPropagation()

```js
var someFunction = function(event){
  alert('<someFunction>');
  
}

var otherFunction = function(event){
  alert("otherFunction ->");
}

var otherFunctionStopPropagation = function(event){
  alert("|otherFunction|");
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
.Some{
  height:200px;
  background-color:yellow;
  z-index:1;
  
}

.other{
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="someFunction()" class="Some">
  <button onclick="otherFunction(event)"  class='other' id='other'>otherFunction</button>
  <button onclick="otherFunctionStopPropagation(event)"  class='other' id='other'>otherFunctionStopPropagation</button>

  <a onclick="otherFunctionStopPropagation(event)" href='' class='other' id='other'>a_otherFunctionStopPropagation</a>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/mastersmind/pen/EbLEBb

Comment: it does work, but you have to stop the event from bubbling to its parent

Comment: Also a side note: How could I also make it ignore <a> tags... or is that for another question?

Comment: @ScottWhite can u elaborate what u mean ignore?

Comment: @mastermind basically my question was if I have `<a href="page2.html">link</a>` inside the container it still calls on `someFunction()` which it looks like you adapted your code to so I'll give that a try and report back. Huge appreciation as always!

Answer (score 0):

You should use event.stopPropogation() function.  This will prevent event getting bubbled to the parent element,

```
otherFunction() {
  event.stopPropagation()
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: you have a typo, it should be `stopPropagation`